# Unable to open MS Word and PDF docs with SFSafariViewController in latest iOS 13.0

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13, sfsafariviewcontroller

We are trying to use SFSafariViewController to browse a Word document from our iOS Mobile app using Swift as it gives ReaderView and Font Increase/Decrease within the App. Everything works as expected on the Simulator with 12.2 ios version, however when we published the changes to TestFlight and started using the app on a real phone ios 13.0 version the SFSafariViewController shows the FileName and says "Open in 'Dropbox' 'More... '"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R595d.jpg

we want to disable/remove that option to choose different apps to open the word/pdf docs and display the content directly within the app. Would greatly appreciate if someone can help remove this option and directly display the documents like below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhFec.png

Below is the code. Can someone please help how to resolve this issue?

```
func openGuidelineSafari(passedURL: String) {  

        let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: " ").inverted  
        let escapedString = passedURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet)  
        let url = URL (string: (escapedString!))  

        let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()  
        config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true  

        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url:url!, configuration: config)  
        vc.delegate = self  
        present(vc, animated: true)  
    }
```

Comment: If you found a solution to this, could you please post what the fix was? Thanks.

Comment: I had this issue today - perhaps it's the same issue. Does the PDF you are trying to use download or display in the browser? If download, then try with an example pdf that displays in the browser
(https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf). Hopefully that works for you. The **content-type** for the example pdf is **application/pdf** whereas the PDF that you're trying to use may be something which forces download.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could resolve it in the backend. The server has to set the following header to view the file directly in a `SFSafariViewController`:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="xyzy"
```